# How to run bat file with arguments from a java program? (Trying to automate using a Command Line Tool )

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to use a command line tool "Tarql" to do some data transformation (providing a csv and sparql query it will transforl the csv file to ttl format).

Comment: You single line command is not correct. It is trying to run, `tarql.bat` located in a directory path `tarql-1.2\bin` located in the root of the drive associated with the current directory at the time you're invoking that intial command. Your larger code snippet, shows the location as `C:\Users\sesa561502\Desktop\Procurment\tarql-1.2\bin`. If your current directory at the time you're invoking that initial command is `C:\Users\sesa561502\Desktop\Procurment`, your command should read `.\tarql-1.2\bin\tarql.bat`, not `\tarql-1.2\bin\tarql.bat`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how usually we pass multiple space-separated commands to process builder

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("command", "command_arg1",
"command_arg2","command_arg3", "command_arg4", ...);
```

If I am running "ls -lrt /home/ubuntu/test" my ProcessBuilder will look like

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "-lrt",
"/home/ubuntu/test");
```

Comment: Something like 
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("\\tarql-1.2\\bin\\tarql.bat", "--write-base",  "--base","http://ontologies.se.com/Proc", "GMap.sparql", "GMap.csv", ">",  "gmap.ttl")